# 500 server error when I re-index my website

Tags: backend, reindex, indexer, http-error-500

When I reindex my website it takes forever and then gives me server 500 error. Is there anything I can do?

Thanks very much[image]

Comment: I have one of the indexes stuck on processing, when I try run indexer from SSH console, I get this error: 500 internal server error
even for the command php shell/indexer.php info
my folder var/locks is empty
running reindex from magento backend end up with blank screen
what is the problem why I can not run indexer on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it from the console instead, if your indexer runs for a long time then you will see this error, you can clean your cookies and login again to the backend to avoid seen this error.

To run the indexer form the console:

```
php shell/indexer.php #this will print the usage information, check it out
php shell/indexer.php info #this will display the available indexes
```

Then:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

If it fails for some reason then you will be able to see the error.

Comment: Sorry, I do I run that command in putty?

Comment: First log in with putty, then move to the directory root of your magento installation and then run the command above. Something like:
cd /var/www/yourmagentoroot/
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

Comment: I see, think I was going mad for a second! That seemed to have worked.

Comment: Great, you can also check your log files for errors in var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log

Comment: This did worked for you? If so can you accept the answer

Comment: Hi there I am still really struggling to get this to work. Surley the re-indexer shouldn't give you a 505 Internal Server Error. I have no idea why it keeps doing it.