# After re-indexing it gives me 505 error

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log

[image: 505 errror]

After re-indexing the Magento 1.9.1

1. It freezes for some time  and
2. Gives 505 error as shown in below snapshot.

I contacted server administrator they say its Magento problem server is working perfectly.

3. There is no error in server log neither in Magento log file

Any suggestion how to resolve this ?

Thank You.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70172/49821
try with this way it might help. 
If you will do indexing by command line.

Comment: Thanks, for reply . I can't run putty on this server I don't have permissions.  Even if I did it for once but I think this will be not a perfect solution, as server person already did 2 times for this website. Is there any other to solve this problem show that it won't happen again.

Comment: Yes I understand it. But in such cases ssh is required try to run commands with php hope it will work.

Comment: @Magento2Learner  I asked server person they did indexing.  But my concern is how can the client do this again and again if indexing required and why this happening. One more thing the database size id 1.5 GB I don't know why. I didn't make this website.

Comment: Indexing creates entry of url_rewrite in table so each time you reindex it will increase size of url_rewrite table. 
if clients need to do this then instead of that you can achieve this by cron job. schedule cronjob for indexing one time in a day. like that.

Comment: for more about database size you can read on this thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large

https://www.fastcomet.com/community/how-to-clear-logs-and-reduce-database-size-in-magento/

Comment: So cronjob don't make entry in database ?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: When you re-index, you can do them without error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login your server via SSH access
and follow below instruction

1. Fire this command `cd /your_magento_root/`
2. Fire command `php -f shell/indexer.php reindex`
3. Wait till above command complete its process
4. Fire command `rm -rf var/cache/*`

   > Fire all above command from your magento root directory

Comment: I can't execute these commands. No privileges.But Re-indexing is done. I have to find why this is happening. Is database size matters. OR some SQL query is stuck making server too busy.

Comment: from your cpanel just delete `var/cache` folder and check if its working for you or not ??

Comment: I used PHP to re-index . In some cases it works in some cases it don't. Do you know how to re-index all using PHP directly.

Comment: I think  your issue with `max_execution_time` increase its value from `php.ini` and check may be it will work ,because reindexing with PHP needs time to execute the script and browser has to wait until that time